# How do single-celled predators chase other cells?

Tags: biochemistry, cell-biology, microbiology

From my understanding, single celled organisms have been seen avoiding, and chasing, potential food or other organisms.

How do they accomplish this? They do not have eyes or ears or a nervous system. My understanding is that chemical reactions are involved somehow.

How do single-celled predators chase other cells? What happens on a chemical level?

**Edit**:*To help keep a more constrained question, the single-celled organism I am considering is [Paramecium](https://microbewiki.kenyon.edu/index.php/Paramecium)*

Comment: This is actually a very broad question. Chemotaxis (the response to changes in a chemical in the environment) is only one of the "taxis". If you could refine this, say by singling out one single celled predator, I think it would be a less broad question.

Comment: @anongoodnurse I am trying to find a common predatory Ciliate that does the behavior that I have described - is Paramecium a good example?

Comment: Yes, paramecium is a good example.

Comment: it is always useful to show work you've done yourself to answer the question.

Comment: @aaaaaa my work so far is essentially google searches leading to links which fail to answer the question. All I can find is definitions of "single-celled organisms", "paramecium", or broad explanations of the digestive system.

Comment: It could be I just don't know the correct terms to search for, if this is readily available information

Answer (score 1):

Detection of and movement according to a gradient of a chemical species is a strategy that single cells use to track a target across space. There are very many strategies of movement depending on the cell and its environment, but a common problem that while cells can sense the concentration of chemicals, they cannot sense its gradient (the direction in which it increases) because they are of too small a size to rely on the difference of concentration on one side and the other. Howard Berg and his co-workers have discovered a mechanism that allows single cells to move toward increasing concentration zones by a combination of concentration sampling and movement. See his webpage, http://www.rowland.harvard.edu/labs/bacteria/projects/track.php